# Fail Protractor on warnings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I looked through the protractor API and reference conf.js but I couldn't find any documentation on how to fail protractor on warnings or how to turn warnings into errors.

Is either of those possible?

Comment: Could you provide an example of a warning? Thanks.

Comment: WARNING - more than one element found for locator ... - the first result will be used

Comment: Why do you need to treat this as an error? Just replace it with `element.all(...).first()`..?

Comment: I don't expect any of my css selectors to find more than one DOM element.  When they do I'd like the test to fail and I don't want to add an expect after each selector to make sure it found exactly one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in in Protractor to treat warnings as errors.

You can redefine the Protractor's [`log.warn()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/logger.js#L30) and throw an error instead of logging a warning:

```
onPrepare: function () {

    var logger = require('protractor/lib/logger.js');
    logger.warn = function (message) {
        throw message;
    };
},
```

Works for me.

---

Also, note that:

> WARNING - more than one element found for locator ... - the first result will be used

This warning can easily be fixed by replacing the:

```
element(...)
```

with:

```
element.all(...).first()
```

Comment: seems like the way the logging is implemented in protractor has changed since this answer, I haven't been able to find a way to do it in 5.4.2. any ideas on how todo it?